# Do While Loop stopping at null pointer

Tags: java, queue, do-while

I have to utilize a do while loop in my Java program for its display method, but I have a Null Exception error when it runs. I have no idea how to incorporate it not being equal to null
The program runs until it gets to the empty Queue.

```
Node<T> currNode = lastNode.next;

System.out.println("The queue elements are: " );
do{
    System.out.print(currNode.data + " ");
    currNode = currNode.next;

}while(currNode != lastNode.next);

System.out.println();
```

Here is my above code, maybe something is wrong here?

```
public class CircularLinkedQueue<T> implements QueueInterface<T> {
    private Node<T> lastNode; // References node for back of queue


    public CircularLinkedQueue() {
        this.lastNode = null;
    } // end default constructor

    public void enqueue(T newEntry) {

        // TODO Project 2A
        Node newNode = new Node(newEntry);
        if (lastNode != null) {
            newNode.next = lastNode.next;
            lastNode.next = newNode;
        } else
            newNode.next = newNode;
        lastNode = newNode;

    } // end enqueue

    public T dequeue() throws EmptyQueueException {

        // TODO Project 2A

        T front = null;
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            if (lastNode.data.equals(lastNode.next.data)) {
                front = lastNode.data;
                this.lastNode = null;
            } else {
                front = lastNode.next.data;
                lastNode.next.data = lastNode.next.next.data;
                lastNode.next.next = lastNode.next.next.next;
            }

        }
        return front; // THIS IS A STUB
    } // end dequeue

    public T getFront() throws EmptyQueueException {
        // TODO Project 2A
        T front;

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            front = lastNode.next.data;
            return front;
        }

        throw new EmptyQueueException();

        // THIS IS A STUB
    } // end getFront

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.lastNode == null;
    } // end isEmpty

    public void clear() {
        this.lastNode = null;
    } // end clear
```

Comment: I tried adding currNode != null into my while statement, but then it runs infinitely

Comment: How did you add that? Because `while (currNode != null);` looks like it should work. Either that or `while (currNode != lastNode);`

Comment: while(currNode != lastNode) and while(currNode != null) prints infinitely, my program wont stop because it prints the name over and over again unless I stop the program run myself

Comment: Then please show how your list was built in the first place.

Comment: And now that I notice it, `Node<T> currNode = lastNode.next;` looks highly suspicious. What is `lastNode`? I would expect it to have a null `next` to begin with.

Comment: so lastNode references the node for the back of the  queue, lastNode.next is just referring to the firstNode. I am enqueue ing names to a CircularLinkedQueue and then getting the front name of the queue and dequeue ing until the queue is empty

Comment: i added most of my other code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a while loop that iterates through all iterator elements, you should do something like this:

```
Node<T> currNode = lastNode.next;
System.out.println("The queue elements are: " );
while(currNode != null) {
     System.out.print(currNode.data + " ");
     currNode = lastNode.next;
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: thank you but unfortunately I have to utilize a do-while loop specifically

Comment: Can you explain why you have to use it?